# Entity Framework, List of List possible?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I wonder if the following is possible to realize with EF 6.0 in C#.

So I have an entity A which has a dict with entities of type B as key and a list of C entities as value:

```
public class A
{
    public int AID { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<B, List<C>> myList { get; set; }

    public somePrimitive AdditionalPropertyOfA { get; set; }
    public somePrimitive AnotherPropertyOfA { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to transform this into a database table A, which looks like the following example:

```
Table A
AID  BID  CID  AdditionalPropertyOfA  ...
1    1    1    ...
1    1    2    ...
1    2    3    ...
1    2    4    ...
2    1    1    ...
2    2    2    ...
2    2    3    ...
2    2    4    ...
```

So I hope it gets clear what I mean. In the above example we would have two A entities, two B entities and four C entities.

For A=1 we have:
B=1: 1->2 and B=2: 3->4

For A=2 we have:
B=1: 1 and B=2: 2->3->4

The problem is that I have no idea how to write this in the entity class A or with the fluent Api. Class A needs to have a n:m mapping to entity B and also needs a n:m mapping to C. But how to bring these things together?

Edit:
To make it more clear what I mean: Think of A's as work plans, B's as employees and C's as tasks for the employees. The B's are entities on their own (name, address, etc.), but within the context of A they have assigned tasks.

Comment: Even if it were possible. This is horrendous Database design. Most programmers/DBAs strive towards higher Normal Forms. This doesn't even make 1NF!

Comment: May be you can use custom mapping of your class file to table. You can use fluent API.

Comment: So what would be a better idea here? Don't use a normal database for entity A and just use a XML file. Or to normalize it and have more problems with the A class in my code? By the way what would be 1NF in this case? How could I realize the custom mapping with Fluent API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This design should probably look like more like the example below.  You haven't given any reason to build out a dictionary, so I don't know why you would want to use one.

```
public class A
{
  public int AID { get; set; }

  public somePrimitive AdditionalPropertyOfA { get; set; }
  public somePrimitive AnotherPropertyOfA { get; set; }

  public virtual ICollection<B> MyBs { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
  public int BID { get; set; }
  public int AID { get; set; }      

  public virtual ICollection<C> MyCs { get; set; }
}

public class C
{
  public int CID { get; set; }
  public int BID { get; set; }      
}
```

Tables:  (for example)

```
Table A
AID  AdditionalPropertyOfA  ...
1    ...
2    ...

Table AB (or AtoB)
AID BID
1   1
1   2
2   1
2   2   

Table B
BID  
1    
2    

Table BC (or BtoC)
BID CID
1   1
1   2
2   2
2   3
2   4

Table C
CID
1
2 
3
4
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea. But now I have the problem that if I asked for a B object, this B object has a collection of MyCs. But only with the additional information from A, B's should be connected to C's. Think of A's as work plans, B's as employees and C's as tasks for the employees. The B's are entities on their own (name, address, etc.), but within the context of A they have assigned tasks.